# JQM (jQueryMobile) Push last page out of DOM on changePage()

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

I notice that the page that I was just viewing is still in the DOM. Is there a way to remove the last page viewed after I transition to the new page using changePage()?

I have disabled all the back navigation as I don't want the use to go back to the last page when transitioning to the new page(s).

Any suggestions?

Flow of the site:

- main page-> fill out info->submit on changePage()
- next page-> fill out more info-> submit on changePage()
- etc...

Once the page has been submitted I don't need it anymore

UPDATE:

Here is the first page:

```
<div data-role="page" 
     id="first_page" 
     data-theme="z" 
     data-backbtn="false" 
     data-url="first_page" 
     class="ui-page 
     ui-body-z">
```

It appends something to this when adding a new page:

```
<div data-role="page" 
     id="next_page" 
     name="next_page" 
     data-theme="z" 
     data-title="next_page" 
     data-url="getNextPage.php?page=next_page" 
     class="ui-page 
     ui-body-z">
```

Calling the live() like this:

```
// pageName[index] = next_page
$('#'+pageName[index]).live('pagecreate',function(event, ui){   
    $(ui.prevPage).remove();
```

using changePage() like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage('getNextPage.php?page='+pageName[index],'slide',false,false);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not exactly knowing your markup I am guessing you are triggering `changePage()` manually.  If that is the case, you could wire up one of the events listed [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/events.html).

> **pageshow**
>   Triggered on the page being
>   shown, after its transition completes.

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
  $(ui.prevPage).remove();
});
```

[**Example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/nT3hg/1/).

Comment: yep that's what I'm doing now. What is the trash part?

Comment: updated my question w/ code example, but implementation of your suggests works in the demo but not my project. Would I pass the prevPage id/name to the remove()?

Comment: Instead of registering the `.live()` against an #id, try placing the `.live()` against any div that is `data-role="page"` `$('div[data-role="page"]').live('pageshow',...`, and try the `pageshow` instead of `pagecreate`

Comment: Hmm that does work in removing the prevPage but pageShow breaks my page functionality as I'm adding custom validation/page rendering of elements before the page is shown. What I'm doing is loading each page from an ajax call so only one page is in memory

Comment: hmmm since you have an array of `id`s, maybe in your `pagecreate` simply do `$('#'+pageName[index]).remove()`?

Comment: that works to remove the prevPage but now the current page doesn't load as it's using pagecreate() instead of pageshow, ugh.....

Comment: After some more testing I found the in the method you offer that ann dialogs will trigger this event as well, remove needed code for functioning pages

Comment: I wish that I could upvote this twice. Thanks a billion!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's related to your issue - but there was a JQM fix that went in yesterday related to errors when attempting to delete DOM elements: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/d4c7b5da66641a3fd081a834ca3d12a5518d499b