# clear everything from the cache/Dom in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi I am developing application using jquery mobile. I have multiple html pages in my application suppose I navigate from page 1 to2 to 3..... In every transition I got response from server. If response from server starts with 0 (eg.0$name^lastname^city$) then I navigate to next page. But suppose response starts from -1 then I have to display login page to user. I can check response and if it starts with -1 then I call `$.mobile.changePage('UI/demo/login.html')`  but now I want to remove all pages which are present in dom, because if I dont remove them then again on back press they will display. How to clear dom.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you want to remove pages for the purpose of logging out / logging a new user in, I would make certain and instead do a [full page refresh](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/link-formats.html)

```
$.mobile.changePage('UI/demo/login.html', {reloadPage : true});
```

Or if it is a link, add this to the link

```
data_ajax="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still need to remove pages from DOM you can do the following:

```
$('div[data-role=page]:hidden').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this from [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737730/jqm-jquerymobile-push-last-page-out-of-dom-on-changepage)

```
$($.mobile.pageContainer).live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    $(ui.prevPage).remove();
});
$.mobile.changePage('UI/demo/login.html')
```

Comment: thanks for reply but I got following error and navigation to login.html does not take place:TypeError: Result of expression 'fromPage.data( "page" )' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile-1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js:2840

Comment: this happens after `pageContainer.empty();` ?

Comment: If I remove changePage then white screen appears and error does not show, but when I click back button then this error appears.

Comment: try `.loadPage` instead of `changePage`

Comment: $.mobile.loadPage('login.html'); does not work using that nothing happens. If I remove $.mobile.pageContainer.empty();
then also page is not navigating to login.html.

Comment: can you attach a handler to `pageshow` event and make smth like `console.log(ui)` and see  what methods and properties does it supply? May be there is smth like `ui.pages`