# jQuery mobile changing page doesn't disable show panel button

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, panel

I have problem disabling the show panel with jq-mobile.

I use templating PHP where each pages share the same header and footer, so I created the html version for this question.

the header has two button which open either left or right panel.
page1.html has 2 panels (left and right), and page2.html has 1 panel (left).

So, in page2.html, the right button panel in the header has to be disabled because page2.html doesn't have right panel.

The problem is, when I open page1 then navigate to page2 via the left panel menu, the right panel header button is not disabled. I specifically add the **ui-disable** class script in page2.html but doesn't work.

If I directly visit page2.html, the button is disabled.

here the source code:

page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HOME</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#index-page", function() {
            $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#index-page", function( e ) {
                if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
                    if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
                        $( "#index-page .right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                    } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                        $( "#index-page .left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="index-page" class="index-page">

        <!--header-->
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>HOME</h1>
            <a id="show-left-panel" href="#left-panel" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-icon-nodisc">Open left panel</a>
            <a id="show-right-panel" href="#right-panel" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-icon-nodisc">Open right panel</a>
        </div><!--/header-->

        <!-- content -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li data-role="list-divider"><h2>Latest News</h2></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <h3>News 1</h3>
                        <p>News news  news  news  news  news  news  news  news  news  news  news  news ...</p>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside">Fri, Feb 14th 2013</p>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <h3>Dummy word example</h3>
                        <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy doug blah blah The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy doug blah blah...</p>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside">Mon, Jan 14th 2013</p>
                    </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <!-- left-panel -->
        <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" class="left-panel" data-display="push">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-count-theme="e">
                <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close</a></li>
                <li data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext"><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /left-panel -->

        <!-- right-panel -->
        <div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" class="right-panel" data-display="overlay" data-position="right">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
                <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close</a></li>
                <li data-role="list-divider">Submenu</li>
                <li data-theme="e">Foo</li>
                <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /right-panel -->

        <!--footer-->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>Copyright &copy; 2013 Example.com</h3>
        </div><!--/footer-->

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HOME</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#index-page", function() {
            $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#index-page", function( e ) {
                if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
                    if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
                        $( "#index-page .right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                    } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                        $( "#index-page .left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#show-right-panel').addClass('ui-disabled'); //if I load page1.html first, than goes here, this line seems to have no effect?
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="index-page" class="index-page">

        <!--header-->
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>HOME</h1>
            <a id="show-left-panel" href="#left-panel" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-icon-nodisc">Open left panel</a>
            <a id="show-right-panel" href="#right-panel" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-icon-nodisc">Open right panel</a>
        </div><!--/header-->

        <!-- content -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li data-role="list-divider"><h2>Subpage</h2></li>
                    <li><a href="#">
                        <h3>SUb 1</h3>
                        <p>News news  news  news  news  news  news  news  news  news  news  news  news ...</p>
                        <p class="ui-li-aside">Fri, Feb 14th 2013</p>
                    </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <!-- left-panel -->
        <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" class="left-panel" data-display="push">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-count-theme="e">
                <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close</a></li>
                <li data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext"><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /left-panel -->

        <!--footer-->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>Copyright &copy; 2013 Example.com</h3>
        </div><!--/footer-->

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/15332886/1920232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your code (not an error because your code is flawless).

In case when jQuery mobile pages are separated in a multiple HTML files, when second HTMl files is loaded into the DOM only its BODY content will be loaded, everything else (including the HEAD) will be discarded.

So your code can be fixed in 2 ways:

1. Move your script content from **page2.html** to **page1.html**
2. Move your script content from **page.2html** HEAD into **page2.html** BODY

Solution one is much cleaner but everyone of them is correct, so choose a solution that better suits you.

One other problem, you cant have 2 pages with a same id, so change a page id inside a **page2.html** file.

More about this topic can be found in my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)** (my personal blog), plus method of prevention with examples.

Comment: apparently my problem is the previous page's DOM still exist in the page. I use solution in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737730/jqm-jquerymobile-push-last-page-out-of-dom-on-changepage  anyway, thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the previous page's DOM still in the active page. So I added the following script to remove it:

```
$( document ).on( "pageshow", "div.big-page", function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.prevPage).remove();
    if($("#right-panel").length > 0) { // make sure the page has right panel
        $("#show-right-panel").removeClass("ui-disabled");
    }
});
```

soure: [JQM (jQueryMobile) Push last page out of DOM on changePage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737730/jqm-jquerymobile-push-last-page-out-of-dom-on-changepage)

Answer (score -1):

Try with a different version of JQM library and css