# Jquery mobile popup doesnt open on Submitting the form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-mobile

There is a `jquery mobile submit form` which I am using to save values into the `SQL database`.
Once the values are stored successfully in DB a popup is opened.

The problem being that the popup doesn't open when the submit button is clicked. I need to click 2 times for the popup to open which in turn would have added 2 database entries.

Code :

```
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        function BuyerDetails() {
            var keys = new Array();
            keys[0] = $('#boardingPassId').val();
            keys[1] = $('#MainContent_totalPrice').val();
            keys[2] = document.getElementById("select-choice-a").options[document.getElementById("select-choice-a").selectedIndex].text;
            keys[3] = $('#email').val();
            keys[4] = $('#Username').val();
            keys[5] = $('#Feedback').val();
            PageMethods.AddToBuyers(keys, onSuccess, onFailure);
        }

        function onSuccess(result) {
            $('#popupDiv').popup("open");
        }

        function onFailure(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    </script>
```

HTML code

```
<div id="page" data-role="page">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3 style="color: white;">Confirmation
        </h3>
        <a data-role="button" onclick="javascript:history.back()" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        <a style="color: white;" data-role="button" data-ajax="false" href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="content-primary">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="email">
                        Boarding pass Number</label>
                    <input id="boardingPassId" type="text" name="input" value="" />
                </li>
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="email">
                        Name</label>
                    <input id="Username" type="text" name="input" value="" />
                </li>
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="email">
                        Total Price</label>
                    <input type="text" name="input1" runat="server" id="totalPrice" readonly="readonly" />
                </li>
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="email" class="select">
                        Payment Method</label>
                    <select name="select-choice-a" id="select-choice-a" data-native-menu="false" style="width: 500px;">
                        <option value="card">Card</option>
                        <option value="cash">Cash</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="email">
                        Feedback(possible improvement/suggestions)</label>
                    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="Feedback"></textarea>
                </li>
                <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="email">
                        Email id</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
                </li>
                <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a">
                            <button type="submit" data-theme="d">
                                Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                            <button type="button" onclick="BuyerDetails()" data-theme="a">
                                Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="content-secondary">
            <div data-role="popup" id="popupDiv" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="b" class="ui-content"
                style="max-width: 340px;">
                <span id="dialog_title_span">Thank You</span>
                <p>
                    Your order has been placed
                </p>
                <a id="productPrice" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-inline="true"
                    href="Default.aspx" data-mini="true">DONE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the popup is not shown when you press once? maybe some background processing is going on and if you wait it may work.

Comment: This is just a buggy jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile popup is little bit buggy, mostly if executed under the Chrome browser.

Classic fix is to put this line:

```
$('#popupDiv').popup("open");
```

inside a setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#popupDiv').popup("open");
},100);
```

1ms should be enough, but you should also test with other values.

I also made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/4yvBK/

Comment: @Gajtores - Thanks for the reply. I did replace `$('#popupDiv').popup("open");` with 

`setTimeout(function(){
    $('#popupDiv').popup("open");
},100);`
That doesn't work either. Changed the timeout for different intervals too. But I still need to click the submit button twice to make the popup appear. The weird fact that the piece of code which opens the popup is hit. But it still doesn't load it.

Comment: And one more thing I would like to add is in IE the popup opens on a single click. This popup problem seems to happen with Firefox and chrome as u said.

Comment: Then I am glad it is working. Popups also usually work in Firefox, this is my first encounter of popup not working in Firefox.